# What really happens when you click the <button>/<input> in HTML?

Tags: java, html, sql

You see, I have this question in my head and this is very simple. I have a situation where I pass a value from my servlet to a parameter that I prepared beforehand. My code is connected to SQL database and I have a delete and edit button. So basically, I would set the value of the buttons with the ID (Company ID to be exact in my case). Now, if either of the button is clicked? Can I have a condional statement where if(button1 != null)? or not? since i have the same value?  I have to have 1 null button so that the code can know what to do. I am afraid that the values I have set up would be fetched even though only one button is clicked.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>View Database</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>View Database</h1>
 <hr>
 <br>
 <br>
 <hr>
 <br>
 <div style="padding-left: 200px">
 <table border = "1px" bordercolor = "black">
 <tr>
 <td>Company ID</td>
 <td>Name</td>
 <td>Contact</td>
 <td>Age</td>
 <td>Gender</td>
 <td>Email</td>
 <td>Position</td>
 <td colspan = "2"> Operations</td>
 </tr>
 <c:forEach items = "${modelList}" var = "list">
 <tr>
 <td>${list.cid}</td>
 <td>${list.name}</td>
 <td>${list.num}</td>
 <td>${list.age}</td>
 <td>${list.gender}</td>
 <td>${list.email}</td>
 <td>${list.position}</td>
 <td><form action = "updateEmployee" method = "post" ><button type="submit" name = "editButton" value = "${list.cid}">Update</button></form></td>
 <td><form action = "updateEmployee" method = "get" ><button type="submit" onclick="alert('Employee deleted!')" name = "delButton" value = "${list.cid}">Remove</button></form></td>
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
 </table>
 </div>
 <br>
 <hr>
 <br>
 <br>
 <hr>
 <p align="right">
  <a href="http://localhost:8080/EmployeeWeb/myHome.jsp" target="_self"><small>Home</small>
  </a> | <a
   href="http://localhost:8080/EmployeeWeb/MyRegistrationPage.jsp"
   target="_self"><small>Register</small> </a> | <a
   href="http://localhost:8080/EmployeeWeb/MyUpdatePage.jsp"
   target="_self"><small>Update</small> </a> | <a
   href="http://localhost:8080/EmployeeWeb/MyDeletePage.jsp"
   target="_self"><small>Delete</small> </a> | <a
   href="http://localhost:8080/EmployeeWeb/MyAboutPage.jsp"
   target="_self"><small>About</small> </a>
 </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can have whatever you are willing and able to code.  Having said that, I find that check boxes or radio buttons are more intuitive for the user and easier to code.

Answer (score 2):

You could have something like this in html

```
<form action="myapiURL" method="get">
<button name="ID" value="Company1ID" type="submit">Company 1</button>
<button name="ID" value="Company2ID" type="submit">Company 2</button>
<button name="ID" value="Company3ID" type="submit">Company 3</button>
<!-- ... -->
</form>
```

then depending on which button is pressed the `ID` param of the request would be set to that buttons value.  Is that what you need?

If you want to **NOT** have the page refresh, then you can use AJAX and send the information, and handle the response.  For example to do the delete:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function btnClick(btn) {
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete: "+btn.innerText+"("+btn.id+")")) {
    // create a request to "up" (is up really the url you are going to send the request to?)
    var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest(), 
        method = "DELETE", 
        url = "up",
        data = new FormData();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      // With the onreadystatechange we can handle the response
      if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        // we will just show an alert with contents to the response for the example.
        alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
    };
    // FormData.append(name, value) - appends a new value onto an 
    //  existing key inside a FormData object, or adds the key if 
    //  it does not already exist.
    data.append("companyId", btn.id);
    data.append("companyName", btn.companyname);
    // now send the data to "up"
    xhr.send(data);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="btnClick(this)" id="CompanyID1" companyname="ACME">Delete ACME</button>
<button onclick="btnClick(this)" id="CompanyID2" companyname="Sears">Delete Sears</button>
<button onclick="btnClick(this)" id="CompanyID3')" companyname="Evil Corp.">Delete Evil Corp.</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course this will try to send a request to stackoverflow.com/post/5046175/up which does not exist so we will get an empty response from it.  But it will send the **parameters** `companyId=<one pressed>` and `companyName=<one pressed>` because I set them in the formdata.

Comment: Sorry i think the term is not parameter but attribute ${att}, And I would like to pass the value of the Company ID to it since I have multiple entries of employee for the database. That will be the value I will now pass to the method that will edit, or delete the entry. Here's some code in my homework.

<td><form action = "up" method = "post" ><button type="submit" name = "editButton" value = "${list.cid}">Update</button></form></td>
 <td><form action = "up" method = "get" ><button type="submit" onclick="alert('Deleted')" name = "delButton" value = "${list.cid}">Remove</button></form></td>

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand your question.  In the code you supply you are setting the button's `type` **attribute** to `submit`, this means it will send the form data to the URL `up`, and reload the page with the response from `up`.  If you don't want it to reload the page, then instead of having the button's `type` **attribute** set to submit, do NOT set its `type` **attribute** at all, rather set the `onclick` **attribute** to a javascript function that uses AJAX to send the request, and handle the response.